# "Cannot override the final method from SherlockActivity"

Tags: android

Am trying to extend my activity with Actionbarsherlock , When i did this i'm getting an error

"Cannot override the final method from SherlockActivity"

My activity has these imports

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.accounts.Account;
    import android.accounts.AccountManager;
    import android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback;
    import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
    import android.accounts.AuthenticatorException;
    import android.accounts.OperationCanceledException;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
```

Kindly guide me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The correct answer is to import the ActionBarSherlock classes, instead of the standard Android ones.

This is from the front page of the ActionBarSherlock project, so obviously this is a common issue:

> Imports
>
> In order to provide functionality that was not available on version of
>   Android prior to 3.0, the library includes and uses a lot of classes
>   that are named the same as their native counterparts. The three most
>   common are:
>
> ```
> com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar
> com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu
> com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem
> com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater
> ```

Answer (score 7):

remove below imports

```
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuInflater;

import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Comment: and replace them with com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu 
com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem 
com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater